# Testing with Jest - reset/clear variables set by tested function and catching console logs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm learning writing unit test with Jest.

I use typescript, but it shouldn't be a problem here. Feel free to provide examples with pure JavaScript.

Until now I have function:

```
const space = String.fromCharCode(0x0020);
const rocket = String.fromCharCode(0xD83D, 0xDE80);
let notified: boolean = false;

export const logHiring = (message: string = "We're hiring!", emoji: string = rocket) => {
    if (!notified) {
        console.info(
            [message, emoji]
                .filter((e) => e)
                .join(space)
        );

        notified = true;
    }
};
```

Yes, function should log to console just one message per initialization.

And *not really working* tests:

```
import {logHiring} from "../index";

const rocket = String.fromCharCode(0xD83D, 0xDE80);

// First test
test("`logHiring` without arguments", () => {
    let result = logHiring();
    expect(result).toBe(`We're hiring! ${rocket}`);
});

// Second test
test("`logHiring` with custom message", () => {
    let result = logHiring("We are looking for employees");
    expect(result).toBe(`We are looking for employees ${rocket}`);
});

// Third test
test("`logHiring` multiple times without arguments", () => {
    let result = logHiring();
    result = logHiring();
    result = logHiring();
    expect(result).toBe(`We're hiring! ${rocket}`);
});
```

I have two problems:

1. How can I test console logs? I've tried `spyOn` without succes.
2. How can I reset internal (from function) `notified` variable for each test?

Comment: Regarding **[2]**, you cannot test module state without externalizing it, but you can test the publicly visible side effects, i.e. it will log to console exactly once when called one or more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I test console logs? I've tried spyOn without succes.

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log')
logHiring();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("We're hiring!")
```

> How can I reset internal (from function) notified variable for each test?

export a getter/setter function like

```
// index.js
export const setNotified = (val) => { notified = val }
export const getNotified = _ => notified

// index.test.js
import { getNotified, setNotified } from '..'
let origNotified = getNotified()
beforeAll(_ => {
  setNotified(/* some fake value here */)
  ...
}
afterAll(_ => {
  setNotified(origNotified)
  ...
}
```